# Divisible orientation preserving diffeomorphism which is time-$1$ map of no smooth flow

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions, discrete-dynamical-systems

Is there an orientation preserving  smooth  diffeomorphism $f$ on a compact manifold $M$ such that

for every  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there  is a  smooth  diffeomorphism   $g:M \to M$,  as  $n$th root of  $f$ (Namely $g^n=f$),  but $f$  is  not the  time-$1$  map  of any  smooth  vector field  on $M$?

In the language of  group action, an extended version of  the  question can be  restated  as follows:

> Is there a  compact orientable manifold $M$ with an action of $\mathbb{Z}$  by smooth orientation preserving diffeomorphisms on $M$ such that the diffeomorphism $x\to 1.x$ is the time- $1$ map of the flow of  no vector field on $M$?

In particular is  there  a  (precise) diffeomorphism $g$  on $2$- torus  with $g^2=f$  where  $f$  is  the  linear Anasov diffdeomorphism  induced by $\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}$?

As a related question: Is $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ a divisible group?

Comment: Rotation by pi/2 has no square root in SL(2,Z). To see this, notice that if it did have a square root, its eigenvalues would be e^{\pm \pi/4} or e^{\pm 5\pi/4}. But the sums of these potential eigenvalues are not integers.

Comment: There is a square root of the $\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}$ map on the torus, namely the $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ map. It does reverse orientation, and there's no orientation preservering square root, and there are no higher roots, as one can show by an eigenvalue argument.

Comment: @LeeMosher   Thank you and +1 for your interesting comment. But we can not conclude that the Anasov linear flow has no (for example) a 3-th root or more generally a nth root dynamical system. Yes?Is it the time 1 map of a flow?

Comment: A diffeomorphism of a smooth manifold $M$ which is the time 1 map of the flow on $M$ generated by a smooth vector field on $M$ is isotopic to the identity on $M$: the flow itself provides the isotopy. But the linear automorphism $g_A$ of the torus defined by a matrix $A \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is isotopic to the identity if and only if $A$ is the identity matrix, because the matrix $A$ gives the action of $g_A$ on the first homology of the torus.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Thank you.for your interesting comment. so with the same  homology argument(with integer coefficients, we  conclude that there is no  homeomorphism  $g$ of torus with $g^3=f$=Anasov diffeomorphism, according to your previous argument in $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's not the appropriate conclusion to make. The appropriate conclusion is that the Anosov linear diffeomorphism $f$ of the torus corresponding to a matrix in $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ (with absolute trace $>2$) has a cube root if and only if that matrix has a cube root in the group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Yes. I think I was saying the same. I meant the homology is  a covariant functor. If  such an g exist. then the induced map $g_{*} $ satisfy $g_{*}^3=f_{*}$. But every induced map must  be an invertible matrix with integer coefficient hence belong $\pm SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.Right?

Comment: That's correct.